# Is there a way to remove focus when trying to make custom form field control from angular material?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-forms

So I'm building a custom form field, but I don't want to force the user to fill the first field first, then second then third like in the [example](https://material.angular.io/guide/creating-a-custom-form-field-control#form-field-custom-control). Is there a way to do this?

[example on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/angular/krydakojpey?file=src%2Fapp%2Fform-field-custom-control-example.ts)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your custom form field looks exactly like the stack blitz; it appears to just be a matter of commenting out/deleting the "onContainerClick()" function at line 194.